# How to share the "using" in multi-files?

Tags: c#, using

I want to wrap some c\c++ dll to c#, and need to write some "using" statement to transfor some types, such as

```
using FoorInteger = int;
```

But it only works in single file. I must copy it to the other files.

How to make it works in multi-files just like the "#define " in c\c++ headers?

Comment: Why not just use the actual types rather than aliasing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in C/C++ because of the [`#include` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?view=vs-2019), which tells the compiler "take everything from this other file and put it in this file". So any `#define` statements you have in the file you included are also defined in the file that has the `#include` directive.

There is no such thing in C#. There are other [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) that are similar to C/C++, but no `#include`. Since you cannot "include" another file, so there is no way to tell the compiler to include the `using` directives from another file.

You will need to copy the `using` directive to every file that uses it.